# SQL - Converting similar data while keeping different data

Tags: sql, oracle

I will try to explain this as detailed as I can if the details are insufficient please help edit my question or inquire about the lacking details for me to add in.

**Problem Description**

I am required to write a SELECT Statement to **convert** the data within **ORDERED_BY** from the REQUESTED_AUTHORS table into **AUTHOR_NAME** data. For example, **JJ** as shown in **ORDERED_BY** must be **converted** into **Jack Johnson** as shown in **AUTHOR_NAME**. Therefore the end results will be **Jack Johnson** instead of  **JJ**. Below shows my 2 tables:

***REQUESTED_AUTHORS***

```
+-----------+
| ORDERED_BY|
+-----------+
|   JJ      |
+-----------+
|   AB      |
+-----------+
|  JonJey   |
+-----------+
|   Admin   |
+-----------+
| Tech Assit|
+-----------+
|  Dr.Ob    |
+-----------+
|   EL      |
+-----------+
|   TA      |
+-----------+
|   JD      |
+-----------+
|   ET      |
+-----------+
```

***AUTHOR_LIST***

```
+----------------+---------------------+
|  ORDER_INITIAL |     AUTHOR_NAME     |
+----------------+---------------------+
|      JJ        |    Jack Johnson     |
+----------------+---------------------+
|      AB        |    Albert Bently    |
+----------------+---------------------+
|     AlecBor    |    Alec Baldwin     |
+----------------+---------------------+
|     KingSt     |      KingSton       |
+----------------+---------------------+
|    GaryNort    |     Gary Norton     |
+----------------+---------------------+
|     Prof.Li    |    Professor Li     |
+----------------+---------------------+
|      EL        |     Elton Langsey   |
+----------------+---------------------+
|      TA        |    Thomas Alecson   |
+----------------+---------------------+
|      JD        |    Johnny Depp      |
+----------------+---------------------+
|      ET        |   Elson Tarese      |
+----------------+---------------------+
```

**Solution Tried (1)**

```
SELECT  ru.*, al.AUTHOR_NAME
FROM REQUESTED_AUTHORS ru, AUTHOR_LIST al
WHERE al.ORDER_INITIAL = ru.ORDERED_BY;
```

But this did not work as I intended it to, as there are different data in both ORDERED_BY and ORDER_INITIAL. I tried using DECODE function in order to convert it but I am stuck there.

**Solution Tried (2)**

```
SELECT ru.ORDERED_BY, 
       al.ORDER_INITIAL,
       DECODE(ru.ORDERED_BY, (ru.ORDERED_BY != al.ORDER_INITIAL), ru.ORDERED_BY,
                            (ru.ORDERED_BY = al.ORDER_INITIAL), al.AUTHOR_NAME)results
FROM REQUESTED_AUTHORS ru, AUTHOR_LIST al;
```

What I intend on doing is changing the data with are similar to the other but keep the different data as how they are.

Meaning that the data as shown below are to be kept the same and not converted as there is nothing for it to convert to.

```
+-----------+
| ORDERED_BY|
+-----------+
|  JonJey   |
+-----------+
|   Admin   |
+-----------+
| Tech Assit|
+-----------+
|  Dr.Ob    |
+-----------+
```

**My Question:**

How may I write a query to convert the similar data and keep the different data?

Comment: Investigate `JOIN` syntax. The answer will become evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an Outer Join (another reason to avoid old-style joins):

```
SELECT  ru.*, 
   -- if there's a match return AUTHOR_NAME, otherwise keep ORDERED_BY 
   COALESCE(al.AUTHOR_NAME, ru.ORDERED_BY)
FROM REQUESTED_AUTHORS ru
LEFT JOIN AUTHOR_LIST al
ON al.ORDER_INITIAL = ru.ORDERED_BY;
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is returning extactly what the OP asked for using Standard SQL (and is supported by Oracle)

Comment: Thank you for your help it works :) and yes this is exactly what I asked for. I have no idea about the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use left outer join here

```
SELECT  ru.*, nvl( al.AUTHOR_NAME , ru.ordered_by)  
FROM REQUESTED_AUTHORS ru, AUTHOR_LIST al
WHERE   ru.ORDERED_BY =  al.ORDER_INITIAL(+);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) . I tried yours as well and it works but I could only accept one answer and so I went with the first one. Sorry